# Why doesn't the container center in Internet Explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer, centering

I have my portfolio, looks great in all browsers but in Internet Explorer the container doesn't seem to center, I'm using `margin: 0 auto;` but it is not working. How can I to fix in Internet Explorer?

Here is the link to the code:
[http://christianbovine.com/](https://web.archive.org/web/20111208091416/http://christianbovine.com/)

Comment: what version of IE? it looks fine on IE8 except for the email me button

Comment: I guess it is the Email button is pushing everything to the Right....which I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of IE require the ingracious use of text-align, like so:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div style="text-align: left; width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <p>Content goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Width is added purely for reference, and margin purely for cross-browser compatibility.

In your case, I'd recommend adding a second "container" div (ie. containerInner), and you could then add something like this in CSS:

```
div#container { text-align: center; }
div#containerInner { text-align: left; }
```

Answer (score 1):

In the parent element, use the "text-align" attribute. For example:

```
body{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-align:center` for the body tag or wrap all content inside a  tag.

Also, you may want to consider using `display:inline-block`. This allows you to specify width and height properties for elements (if it's just set to inline and not block, width and height attributes are ignored) if it's the case.